# Mathematica doesn't generate PDF correctly

Tags: pdf-format

When saving my notebook as PDF Mathematica 12.0 does not print special caracters (<, >, :, ;, and so on) and numbers correctly. My example:
[image: Special characters and numbers printed incorrectly]

It never happened in previous versions. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: This sounds like a problem which might be dependent on the operating system (or maybe more specifically, "operating environment") you are using. Can you provide further details on the environment?

Comment: The V12 again has problems with non-Unicode fonts in notebooks as well as in file-path. The solution is to choose the font where your symbols are looking good and save the pdf with it

Comment: I'm using opensuse's tumbleweed (linux). Maybe I need to install new fonts on the system

Comment: I tried this with MMA 12.0 in MacOS 10.13.6 (High Sierra), and the pdf was was fine.  So it does seem to be, as @kirma said, dependent on your operating environment.

Comment: @theorist I also think that although it's very likely one can fix the configuration, OpenSUSE Tumbleweed is not really on the list of supported platforms of Mathematica. I think I have run into some intriguing issues when running Mathematica on such fresh platforms, such as MacOS beta. Sadly I can't say much on how this specific problem could be fixed...

Comment: To confirm the problem is really due to the tumbleweed release system, it would be helpful if the OP could try it on OpenSUSE's standard (Leap) release, which is officially supported (OpenSUSE Leap 42.3, 15).